# gt::gtsave throws error 'Invalid path to Chrome' (save a .png via webshot)

Tags: r, gt, webshot

I have an issue with some code that perfectly worked previously with my setup. I assume it fails now after `webshot2` has superseded `webshot`. Anyway, I am not able to fix the following error.

Aim: I want to process data via teh `gt` package and save them through `gt::gtsave()` as a .png file.

Reprex:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)
library(webshot)
library(webshot2)
 
 
df <- iris %>%
  slice(1:10)
 
table <- gt(df)
 
gtsave(table, paste("iris",".png",sep=""),expand=0,vwidth=350,vheight=240,zoom=3)
```

Everything works and is yielding a fine table until I attempt saving. I have searched the internet and found little help, yet tried some proposed fixes (more randomly, since they did not perfectly match my issue). Please note that I do have MS Edge installed (which worked fine previously) and nothing else was changed in regard of relevant hardware or software.

Error is the following:

```
Error trying to find path to Chrome
Error in initialize(...) : Invalid path to Chrome
```

Is it really due to the web shot not being able to recognize Edge installation or do I have to familiarize/customize my code to headless chrome (how?). Essentially, what can I do to make R/Rstudio recognize the Edge installation and save my .png?

Comment: Were you able to fix it? I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

so we finally managed :)
`gt` uses webshot2 and this un turn uses `chromote`. So, first, check if it finds the route chrome:

```r
    chromote::find_chrome()
```

And if it doesn't find it, just assign it as:

```r
    Sys.setenv(CHROMOTE_CHROME = "your route to/chrome.exe")
```

double-check with `chromote::find_chrome()` and you should see your route, and then it works.

In this same way, you can assign a different web browser

More info [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chromote/readme/README.html) and [here](https://%20https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/chromote/readme/README.html#specifying-which-browser-to-use).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, many thanks! Ill try that again. 

Best, Bernhard